# What does this means in Logbook?

Tags: android

I am not sure what this means; is there anyone who knows what this is? It is another part of my error from the previous question. Any point of view on this?

```
2020-06-04 15:02:15.052 5221-32592/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting service_kind=0 source=16 tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG target_package=com.google.android.gms requires_charging=0 source_version=201817000 required_network_type=0 flex_time=1224000 persistence_level=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService runtime=1591254135010 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} preferred_network_type=1 required_idleness_state=0 preferred_charging_state=1 period=2449000 last_runtime=0 task_type=0 job_id=-1 user_id=0
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
        #################################################################
        Error Code : 2067 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
            (UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067))
        #################################################################
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:865)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1862)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1732)
            at apla.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):78)
            at apkp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):196)
            at apkp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):20)
            at apkp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):190)
            at apgy.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):8)
            at sji.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):12)
            at sji.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):7)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
            at spj.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817019@20.18.17 (040400-311416286):0)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a table in sqlite database. That contains some columns which accepts unique key values.

As an example:

You have a table name **users**, and you have a column named **user_id** inside that table which only accepts unique key values. Now if you have a user inside your table who's **user_id** is **1**, then you can't create any other user with the same **user_id**. If you try so in those kinda situation you'll get **UNIQUE constraint failed** error.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Most of the data is from firebase; how does it relate? unless is from my model which has 4 different models but consist of the same constructor, getter and setter

Comment: Are you using sqlite?

Comment: No, is just firebase storage, database and authentication